# How do I inject a Spring dependency by ID?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, annotations

I have several beans with the same type (`BeanType`). How do I inject them by ID with an annotation? Say:

```
@Autowired @ID("bean1")
public void setBean( BeanType bean ) {
}
```

But there is no annotation `@ID`.

I only found `@Qualifier` which would mean that I would have to give all my beans IDs *and* qualifiers. Surely, there is a more simple way?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Simplest solution is to use `@Resource`

```
@Resource(name="bean1")
public void setBean( BeanType bean ) {
}
```

Incidentally, `@Qualifier` *is* used to refer to beans by ID for use with `@Autowired`, e.g

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("bean1")
public void setBean( BeanType bean ) {
}
```

where `bean1` is the ID of the bean to be injected.

See the [Spring manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers):

> For a fallback match, the bean name is considered a default qualifier value. Thus you can define the bean with an id "main" instead of the nested qualifier element, leading to the same matching result. However, although you can use this convention to refer to specific beans by name, `@Autowired` is fundamentally about type-driven injection with optional semantic qualifiers. This means that qualifier values, even with the bean name fallback, always have narrowing semantics within the set of type matches; they do not semantically express a reference to a unique bean id.

and

> If you intend to express annotation-driven injection by name, do not primarily use `@Autowired`, even if is technically capable of referring to a bean name through `@Qualifier` values. Instead, use the JSR-250 `@Resource` annotation, which is semantically defined to identify a specific target component by its unique name, with the declared type being irrelevant for the matching process.

I prefer `@Resource`, it's cleaner (and not Spring-specific).

Comment: Hmm... then I must have done something wrong because @Qualifier finds no beans.. `@Resource` works though. Can you please check that `@Qualifier` really works for IDs? According to the docs, it needs an `<qualifier >` element in the bean.

Comment: @Aaron: The behaviours of each approach are actually subtly different. When using `@Qualifier` with `@Autowired`, the qualifier is used to narrow down the options presented by `@Autowired`, whereas `@Resource` explicitly selects a bean by name.

Comment: Seems that in my case, @Autowired preselects the wrong beans, so @Qualifier doesn't help anymore.