# @Resource annotation applied on setter method is returning the null pointer exception when using getter method to get the value

Tags: java, spring

I have a simple class called circle which has a property called center,  I have a simple class called circle which has a property called center, on which i have applied @Resource annotation to inject the dependency from spring.xml but somehow the center value is not injecting from spring.xml that is why i am getting null pointer exception while getting the value.
i have a bean defined in xml  with the same name as the name of property of circle

```
     //Circle class:

        package org.devesh.learning.spring;

        import javax.annotation.Resource;

        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;

public class Circle implements Shape {

    private Point center; 

    @Override
    public void draw() {

      System.out.println("Circle drawn");
      System.out.println("Circle center is : "+ center.getX() + "," + center.getY());       
    }

    public Point getCenter() {
        return center;
    }

    //@Autowired
    //@Qualifier("circle related")
    @Resource
    public void setCenter(Point center) {
        this.center = center;
    }

}


Point class:

package org.devesh.learning.spring;

public class Point {

    private int x;
    private int y;


    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }



}

spring.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
         https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

     <bean id="circle" class="org.devesh.learning.spring.Circle">
     </bean>

       <bean id ="pointA"  class="org.devesh.learning.spring.Point">
      <property name="x" value="${pointA.pointX}"></property>
      <property name="y" value="${pointA.pointY}"></property> 
  </bean>


   <bean id = "center" class="org.devesh.learning.spring.Point"> 
      <property name="x" value="20"></property>
      <property name="y" value="0"></property> 
  </bean>


  <bean id = "pointC" class="org.devesh.learning.spring.Point">
      <property name="x" value="-20"></property>
      <property name="y" value="0"></property> 
  </bean>

   <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="locations" value="pointconfig.properties"></property>  
 </bean>



</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple beans of the same point type, inject center by its ID,
@Resource(name="center")

[How do I inject a Spring dependency by ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648655/how-do-i-inject-a-spring-dependency-by-id)

Comment: i had tried this, but using bean id is also giving same error . in turtorial it is mentioned when we are not using any paremeter in resource annotation it takes the bean which has same name as property on which we are applying the annotation so it should have been worked without giving bean id as name is same though there are multiple beans of same type